# Existe alguma ferramenta ou método que me permita receber notificações no desktop para novas perguntas com minhas tags favoritas?

Tags: suporte

Já deu uma pesquisada no Google mas só encontrei ferramentas que me permitam obter notificações desktop para respostas de perguntas específicas. Mas eu gostaria de receber notificações para novas perguntas com minhas tags favoritas. Tem como?

Comment: Não sei se exite algo da forma que deseja, mas você pode filtrar por [Desktop no Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/search?q=desktop) e ver se acha o que deseja. Todavia, você sempre pode utilizar a [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) e criar o que deseja.

Comment: @arthur sabe usar os Feeds?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Nunca usei, mas os feeds não são para acompanhar uma pergunta específica?

Comment: @arthur editei a resposta e coloquei a explicação sobre os Feeds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lhes apresento o [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) um site da rede *Stack Exchange* dedicado a desenvolver apps para qualquer site ou todos da rede.

Dois apps que fazem isso:

- [New Q! - Google Chrome Extension notifies you of new questions of interest and inbox messages (now with API v2.0!)](https://stackapps.com/q/587/33963)
- [StackApplet — Bringing Stack Exchange Notifications to Your Desktop [Large scale rewrite in progress]](https://stackapps.com/q/83/33963)

### Feeds uma boa escolha

Eu pessoalmente gosto muito dos feeds, mas percebo que as pessoas não entendem bem o uso dele, o proposito deles é este mesmo, te manter informado sem precisar abrir um site especifico, claro que você ainda vai precisar escolher o seu *cliente de feed*, o Opera e Firefox tem clientes nativos, o Chrome tem alternativas na ChromeStore, existem clientes web, vou postar com o tempo aqui, os feeds que o site possuem são:

- Feed das perguntas recentes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/feeds
- Feed de uma perguntas especifica: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/54177
- Feed por tag (exemplo da tag [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)):

  - Mais recentes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c
  - Mais votadas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c&sort=votes

> Pessoalmente eu gosto muito de feeds, o que falta é um cliente mais *friendly* (intuitivo na verdade) para quem não tem experiencia

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme. O StackApplet no entanto pelo que eu li na descrição, possui a funcionalidade de alertar apenas eventos relacionados a conta do usuário. Instalei ele aqui e ele parece mesmo não ter a funcionalidade de acompanhar novas perguntas com uma tag. Já New Q! possui sim essa funcionalidade, pena que parece ser apenas para o SO-EN, mas já ajuda bastante. Vou ver se consigo sugerir ao autor para adicionar o SO-PT. Obrigado.